# Akka and Typesafe config versions issue

Tags: scala, version, config, akka

I tried to use akka 2.1.0 on a Tomcat server. But I got an error asking me to put the config library on the classpath too.

Well that's not the issue. I put the config library of Typesafe, version 1.0.0 (the latest) in the lib folder. However, I always get the error

```
8d31597e-1b6e-4be5-9773-4fb7e0591312akka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.1.0] does not match the provided config version [2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:465)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
```

The jar files in the lib folder are :

- akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar
- config-1.0.0.jar
- scala-library-2.10.0.jar

Where does this problem come from ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It loads a configuration file containing `akka.version=2.0` but is expecting `2.1.0`.
You might have mistakenly defined `akka.version` in your `application.conf`. Remove that setting. Otherwise you have a akka-actor 2.0 jar file in your classspath.